# two way infinite turing machine?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

A Single tape turing machine is generally unbounded to right and starts from left. Read/write head moves to right from left after consuming a symbol. But what if we make left side unbounded too and make read/write head movable in both the directions? Will it increase it's power?

edit : Actually it's been answered at cs.stackexchange.com 
Answer is Yes they are Equal in Power, can be simluated by one another.
Link is https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22863/turing-machine-infinite-tape-in-one-or-two-directions

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

This has already been answered

> "In spite of the appearance of being more powerful computational tool,
>   multi-tape TM are computationally equivalent to standard TM’s with one
>   tape."

[Link to Source if you want to check authenticity](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~goldberg/13-CC/03-TM-types.pdf)

Comment: That's multitape, means more than one tapes but with single Read/Write head. The head moves to tapes. It can be simulated by Single tape Turing machine, Similarly MultiTrack can be simulated by single tape turing machine.But what I am asking is single tape but unbounded in both the directions.